# Запретить пробелы в EditText

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Есть компонент:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/elMail"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/famil"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Электронная почта"
    android:maxLength="35"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

Каким образом можно запретить ввод в данное поле пробелов?
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        boolean keepOriginal = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char c = source.charAt(i);
            if (isCharAllowed(c)) // put your condition here
                sb.append(c);
            else
                keepOriginal = false;
        }
        if (keepOriginal)
            return null;
        else {
            if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return sb;
            }           
        }
    }

    private boolean isCharAllowed(char c) {
        return c != ' ';
    }
}
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Или прям в разметке наоборот указать доступные символы:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/elMail"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/famil"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Электронная почта"
    android:maxLength="35"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" />
```